Cross cluster replication for Elastic search community edition
I am using elastic search community version. I want to implement cross cluster replication for disaster recovery. I gone through cross cluster replication of elastic search but this is supported only for enterprise edition. Is there any open source solution available for this ?
I am also thinking to use kafka elastic source connector and elastic sink connector for data syncing. Looking for suggestion and best approach to implement cross cluster replication for community edition.
